# Any risk to consider when implementing IDisposable?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I want to created a method that calls a  repository class in a  using() statement. That class is not currently disposable. Is there anything I should consider before making it implement IDisposable?

i.e.

```
using(var repo = new RespositoryClass() )
{
   //do work
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to implement `IDisposable`?  The fact that it uses a disposable resource doesn't mean it needs to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Servy: post that as an answer; it's the correct one!

Comment: Your question seems pretty broad. I can't think of anything specific cause I don't know what you're concerned about, but here's a good article that can put the right light on your development. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About

Comment: The question is unclear. Which class do you want to make IDisposable and why? (Ie what are the resources?)

Comment: Why do you want to use a using block on something that doesn't already implement IDisposable? Sounds like cart before the horse.

Comment: I did not want to make the class calling the repo Disposable I was reffering to the Repository itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement `IDisposable` if the class uses unmanaged resources, or initializes other members that implement it. Otherwise, don't use it if you don't need it.

Comment: * has other members /which it owns/ that implement IDisposable. You don't want to dispose an object you hold reference to if something else is responsible for / using it.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you use an `IDisposable` object inside a class does not mean that the class needs to implement IDisposable.

The example class below doesn't need to implement `IDisposable`.

```
class NotDisposable
{
  public void someMethod()
  {
    using(SomethingDisposable resource = new SomethingDisposable ())
    {...}
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a class that *would* need to implement `IDisposable`.

```
class SomethingToDispose : IDisposable
{
  private SomethingDisposable resource = new SomethingDisposable();

  public void someMethod()
  {
    //code that uses resource 
  }

  //code to dispose of "resource" in a Dispose method.
}
```

As you can see in this second example there isn't really anywhere for the class to put a `using` statement to dispose of the resource.  Since it's storing the disposable object in a field, and it is the one responsible for disposing of it, the best way of ensuring that it gets disposed is to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: The repository class _does_ need to be disposable because it is called with a `using` statement

Comment: atbyrd changed the question to include `using` after Servy posted this answer.